# Background slider for ionic v1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am currently working of a ionic v1 project and i need to add a background slideshow for the application but cannot find how to do that in ionic. I have tried https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/background-slideshow/ but i need something that works with angular.js. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ion-content scroll="false" class="padding">
 <div class="full">
    <div class="half">
  <ion-slides options="options" slider="data.slider">
    <ion-slide-page>

        <center>    <i class="ion-android-archive homefont"></i>
   <h2>Post a request</h2>
   <p></p>
      </center>
    </ion-slide-page>
    <ion-slide-page>
        <center>    <i class="ion-locked homefont"></i>
   <h2>Safe Deposit</h2>
   <p></p>
      </center>
    </ion-slide-page>
    <ion-slide-page>
      <center>  <i class="ion-plane homefont"></i>
   <h2>Traveller Fulfills</h2>
   <p></p>
      </center>
    </ion-slide-page>
  </ion-slides>
  </div>
  <div class="2half">
 <div class=" padding-top">
     <center > <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="logo" width=80 height=80></center>
     </div>
   <div class=" padding-vertical">
  <button class="button button-block button-positive">
 Post Your Request
</button></div>
<button class="button button-block button-positive">
  Post Your Trip
</button>
</div>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

> class full will have a height of 100% while half and 2half will both have a height of 50% and display value is block.
>
> > to make the slider to a full background slider class half height will be 100%